Getting error while using Add-Migration Initial
I have been trying to use code first approach to create a database via already written models and context class. Below is my context class for reference.
using BankLibrary.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class BankDBContext : DbContext
{
public BankDBContext()
{
}

public BankDBContext(DbContextOptions<BankDBContext> options) : base(options)
{
}

public DbSet<AccountHolderDetails> AccountDetails { get; set; }
public DbSet<TransactionDetails> TransactionDetails { get; set; }
public DbSet<LoanDetails> LoanDetails { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; database=BankDB;    integrated security=true");
}

}
But I have been getting the error:
enter image description here
I don't know how to resolve it. I could not find any solution online. I have used this same code before for other projects but this time, I am getting the above error. Can anyone please help me with this?
I have already tried changes suggested by ChatGPT and reinstalled the packages (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) as instructed. Still did not resolve the error.

Try to set context manually like
Add-Migration Initial --context BankDBContext

Try to remove the empty constructor. I have had this issue in the past and it was the root cause of the error.
